# SQL Logic for Latest record from results obtained

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I build that pulls back data from multiple tables for a particular location, particular appointment types in a schedule for a particular date range. In the data that is returned, I am pulling the provider of the service, the member who is getting the service and a number of fields that describe things about the member or service appointment. The information will be grouped by the provider. So you will have multiple members/client records per provider for that period.

What I am now being asked to do is to take those results and pull only the latest appointment for those results.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT        SCSERVICES.servicecode, SCSERVICES.servicename, SCSESSIONS.scheduleid, SCSERVICES.servicetype, SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory, 
                     SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, SCSCHEDULES.timestart, SCSCHEDULES.schedulestatus, 
                     CASE WHEN MEMBERS.phone1label = '4' THEN MEMBERS.phone1 WHEN MEMBERS.phone2label = '4' THEN MEMBERS.phone2 WHEN MEMBERS.phone3label = '4'
                      THEN MEMBERS.phone3 WHEN MEMBERS.phone4label = '4' THEN MEMBERS.phone4 END AS MobilePhone, MEMBERS.scancode, 
                     EMPLOYEES.fname AS trainfname, EMPLOYEES.lname AS trainlname, MEMBERS.lastvisit
FROM            SCSESSIONS INNER JOIN
                         SCSERVICES ON SCSESSIONS.serviceid = SCSERVICES.serviceid INNER JOIN
                         SCSERVICECATEGORIES ON SCSERVICES.servicecategoryid = SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategoryid INNER JOIN
                         SCSCHEDULES ON SCSESSIONS.scheduleid = SCSCHEDULES.scheduleid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS ON SCSCHEDULES.memid = MEMBERS.memid INNER JOIN
                         SCSESSION_PROVIDERS ON SCSESSIONS.sessionid = SCSESSION_PROVIDERS.sessionid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SCSESSION_PROVIDERS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Trainers' OR
                         SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Pilates' OR
                         SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Specialty') AND (SCSERVICES.siteid = @rvSite) AND (CAST(SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom AS DATE) BETWEEN 
                         @rvSessionDate AND @rvSessionDateEnd) AND (SCSCHEDULES.schedulestatus = '1') AND (SCSERVICES.servicecode <> 'BREAK')
```

Results look something like this:

[image]

Comment: `ORDER BY SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom DESC` and `TOP 1` ?

Comment: Add a outer select from this and select whatever you want and use where condition. Use order by desc and get the top 1

Select top 1 from (Paste your above query order by column desc) a

Comment: Please consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Also you will probably find [RANK window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can use row_number function for that 
 ( for latest scheduledatefrom for a member)

```
select * from (

SELECT SCSERVICES.servicecode
    , SCSERVICES.servicename
    , SCSESSIONS.scheduleid
    , SCSERVICES.servicetype
    , SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory
    , SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom
    , MEMBERS.lname
    , MEMBERS.fname
    , SCSCHEDULES.timestart
    , SCSCHEDULES.schedulestatus
    , CASE 
        WHEN MEMBERS.phone1label = '4'
            THEN MEMBERS.phone1
        WHEN MEMBERS.phone2label = '4'
            THEN MEMBERS.phone2
        WHEN MEMBERS.phone3label = '4'
            THEN MEMBERS.phone3
        WHEN MEMBERS.phone4label = '4'
            THEN MEMBERS.phone4
        END AS MobilePhone
    , MEMBERS.scancode
    , EMPLOYEES.fname AS trainfname
    , EMPLOYEES.lname AS trainlname
    , MEMBERS.lastvisit
    ,    row_number() over ( partition by MEMBERS.memid order by SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom desc) rowid
FROM SCSESSIONS
INNER JOIN SCSERVICES
    ON SCSESSIONS.serviceid = SCSERVICES.serviceid
INNER JOIN SCSERVICECATEGORIES
    ON SCSERVICES.servicecategoryid = SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategoryid
INNER JOIN SCSCHEDULES
    ON SCSESSIONS.scheduleid = SCSCHEDULES.scheduleid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS
    ON SCSCHEDULES.memid = MEMBERS.memid
INNER JOIN SCSESSION_PROVIDERS
    ON SCSESSIONS.sessionid = SCSESSION_PROVIDERS.sessionid
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES
    ON SCSESSION_PROVIDERS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE (
        SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Trainers'
        OR SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Pilates'
        OR SCSERVICECATEGORIES.servicecategory = 'Specialty'
        )
    AND (SCSERVICES.siteid = @rvSite)
    AND (
        CAST(SCSCHEDULES.scheduledatefrom AS DATE) BETWEEN @rvSessionDate
            AND @rvSessionDateEnd
        )
    AND (SCSCHEDULES.schedulestatus = '1')
    AND (SCSERVICES.servicecode <> 'BREAK')
) x 
where rowid = 1
```

Comment: When I implement the suggested code, I receive the following error: "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Comment: which sql server you have? row_number function is available from sql server 2008.

Comment: I am working with SQL 2008. If you wouldn't mind, a little help with the syntax of the row-number would greatly help. Thank you!

Comment: here is a link to official description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx